# Attach user specific Id to .msi setup

Tags: c#, windows-installer, windows-forms-designer

In our system we do have a link for customers to download a .msi setup which they are gonna install on their PC.

I just need to way to track which .msi setup was installed by which customer. The .msi setup is common for everyone but need a way to record who installed the setup.

Ex: probably a way to attach the customer id to the .msi setup when they download it? and then we make an API call from the setup installed PC to our hosted API

What should be the approch in a situation like this?

Thanks

Comment: I'd say, that the easest way would be a creation of a bootstrapper. Bootstrapper could collect all the necessary information about a customer, then download MSI, then install MSI and after installation report you, the result.

Comment: The user name can be written to registry as part of installation if you modify the MSI a little with a transform. You can also find the UserSid of the user who added a certain MSI component to the registry via the MSI API COM interface. Just a couple of hints - can't add any more details right now.